# How to compare a string with EOF?

Tags: c, linux

I've created a program that acts like a unix-shell. Namely if type something like "./helloWorld" it will execute the program and then wait for additional input. If the input is EOF (Ctrl + D) then the program must terminate.

What I'm struggling with is trying to compare the input without using getchar() or any method that requires additional input.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<unistd.h> /* for fork() */
#include<sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include<sys/wait.h> /* fpr wait() */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    pid_t pid,waitPid;
    int status;
    char fileName[256];
    while(!feof(stdin))
    {
    printf(" %s > ", argv[0]);
    if (fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin) != 0)
    {
        fileName[strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0'; //strcspn = calculates the length of the initial fileName segment, which  consists of chars not in str2("\n")

    char *args[129];
    char **argv = args;
    char *cmd = fileName;
    const char *whisp = " \t\f\r\b\n";
    char *token;
    while ((token = strtok(cmd,whisp)) != 0) // strtok = breaks string into a series of tokens using the delimeter delim(whisp)
    {
        *argv++ = token;
        cmd = 0;
    }// /while

    if (getchar() == EOF)
    {
    break;
    }

    *argv = 0;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
    execv(args[0], args);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops! \n");
    } // /if
    waitPid = wait(&status);



}// /if(fgets..)
} // /while
return 1;
```

}

I want to replace the

```
if (getchar() == EOF)
        {
        break;
        }
```

with a direct comparison. Like so: if (fileName == EOF) { break; }

Is this even possible? I've tried casting and other methods,but nothing has worked so far. Is there a different method that I haven't thought of?
To be more clear, I want to know if my thought is doable and if it is how to implement it. If not how can I terminate my program with CTRL + D and without additional input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way of comparing a string with EOF; it is not a `char` value, but a condition on the stream (here, `stdin`). However the `getchar()` and alike will return the *read `char` value* as `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, **or `EOF` if end-of-file was reached, or an error occurred.**

---

The man page for `fgets` says:

> `fgets(s, size, stream)` returns `s`  on success, and `NULL` on error or ***when end of file occurs while no characters have been read***.

After you get `NULL` from `fgets` you can use `feof(stdin)` to test whether or not you've reached the end-of-file; or if it was because of an error; likewise you should be able to check the return value `feof(stdin)` after reading each line with `fgets`. If `feof(stdin)` returns 0, then the end-of-file was not yet reached; if the return value is non-zero, it means that the EOF was reached.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. It solved my problem. I wrote if ( feof(stdin)) { break; }